# NVL function not using index rather FTS, is it possible to modify the query

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-tuning, database-tuning, query-tuning

MY query like below

```
select  nvl(a.value1,nvl(b.value1,nvl(c.value1,''))
 from table1 a, table2 b table3 c 
where a.value2=b.value2 and b.value3=c.value3
```

As this query contains a nvl function which tables the value1 from three of my tables it is making a full table scan , i understand if i can make a function based index oracle should consider that index, but my concern is as the nvl function is on columns of three different tables i am unable to craete function based index, any otherway to rewrite the query or any otherway i can use index here,  help please

Comment: Are you sure the nvl is causing your problem - you aren't using it in a join condition so it seems odd that index/FTS is affected? Incidentally, `nvl(c.value1,'')` is pointless as `''` is the same as null in Oracle; and you should consider using modern join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce` function as follows:

```
Coalesce(a.value1, b.value1, c.value1)
```

Or you can use the `case when` statement as follows:

```
Case when a.value1 is not null then a.valie1
     When b.value1 is not null then b.value1
     Else c.value1
End
```

**Note**: performance of `coalesce` is better than the `NVL`, as `coleasce` uses the short-circuit evaluation means it evaluates the arguments only if they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to make a definitive comment on a query without seeing an execution plan. I don't think you can create a function-based index on multiple tables simultaneously. Honestly, I doubt the NVL is much of a bottleneck. What you might do is make three indexes:

```
create index idx1 on table1( value2, value1 );
create index idx2 on table2( value3, value2, value1 );
create index idx3 on table3( value3, value1 );
```

At least then, Oracle won't have to get the full row for each table.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that